# Division Rule - Basic Counting

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Can we apply the division rule to this problem :

On each of the 22 work days in a particular month, every employee of a start-up venture was sent a company communication. If a total of 4730 company communications were sent, how many employees does the company have, assuming that no staffing changes were made that month?

From the Discrete math book :

*If the finite set A is the union of n pairwise disjoint subsets each with d elements, then n = |A|/d*

Using this formula from the book, I calculated this to be 4730/22 = 215

Can you please confirm if this is correct and if my understanding is right, because the book mentions this to be a hard problem and I am not sure if I am missing something ?

Comment: "*the book mentions this to be a hard problem*"  Does it?  Hard conceptually perhaps... hard to understand the usefulness of this and how to apply it to far more abstract scenarios, hard to prove the fully generalized concept for a beginner perhaps... but in the end yes, all that is required here is to simply divide $4730$ by $22$ to get the answer of $215$.  You may also see this referred to as the "Shepherd's Principle" in other books or literature.  [See also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_division_(combinatorics)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how this is a discrete math or combinatorics problem. You can solve it without any of those tools. Think about it like this:

$$\text{Total Communications} = \text{Number of Employees} \times \text{Number of Days}
$$

This suffices because the problem states that *every employee* receives the communication on *every workday*. So you can treat employees as one unit and the days as one unit, rather than needing to think about subsets of them.

A classic combinatorial problem would involve needing to tackle subsets of either employees or days.